# Why, with apk split per ABI, a different apk from the one just built is installed?

Tags: android, android-studio

I am using Android Studio 2.2.2, Gradle 2.14.1, and the following splits:

```
splits {
    abi {
        enable true
        reset()
        include "armeabi-v7a", "mips", "x86"
        universalApk true
    }
}
```

When trying to "Run 'app'" on Huawei EVA-L19 and ALE-L21, it tries to install a different apk than it just built: builds "universal" and tries to install "armeabi-v7a", resulting in:

```
07/07 13:04:07: Launching app
The APK file (...)\app-dev-armeabi-v7a-debug.apk does not exist on disk.
Error while Installing APK
```

It's even worse when there IS an old V7 build in the folder, and hours are wasted making changes in the code to no effect, as it keeps installing the same one.

We do not plan to make separate builds for 64-bit architectures; the expected behavior for "arm64-v8a" is to build and install "armeabi-v7a" - and that is what happens when universalApk is set to false.

[Instant Run](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37109398) is disabled.

Where does the cause lie and how to fix it?

Comment: Can you check what selected inside Run->Run/Debug Configurations->Installation Options-> Deploy

Comment: @BrijeshMasrani Run | Edit Configurations | Android App/app, General tab, Deployment Target Options shows "Open Select Deployment target Dialog". "Same Device for future launches" is deselected.  Installation Options is "default APK". Most everything here is left as default.

Comment: why is armeabi-v7a version of apk not generated? Since ABI split is enabled studio is trying to find the relevant apk to the connected phone.

Comment: one more question, if you are splitting apk why do u still want a universal apk

Comment: @BrijeshMasrani armeabi-v7a apk is generated when I Run on a V7 architecture phone.  "Run" only builds one of the splits, the one for the current device.  As for Universal - not my call, someone wants - or wanted in the past - to use some test-related tool that could only accept a single apk. But let's not focus too much on that - either there is something wrong with my config, or it's a Studio bug that needs to be reported.

Answer (score 1):

Not solution, but some workaround:

set `universalApk` option from property:

```
splits {
    abi {
        enable true
        reset()
        include "armeabi-v7a", "mips", "x86"
        universalApk !project.hasProperty('notUniversal')
    }
}
```

and then in your `Android Studio` => `Settings` => `Build, Execution, Deployment` => `Compiler` => `Command-line Options:` add property flag: `-PnotUniversal`

after that:

when you trying to `Run/Debug app` build will be like `universalApk false` and `armeabi-v7a` .apk will created.

but when you call `./gradlew` from command-line or i.e. at TeamCity => it will be called like `universalApk true` and build all variants (with universal)